# Having challenge with xml file

Tags: python, xml, loops, parser-combinators

want to print this xml file such that I can be able to loop through it. my aim is to combine it with a csv file having the same column name, before creating a database with this combined file. I'm not allow to use non standard Libraries.

code------

xml_file = ET.parse("E:/Research work/My connect/Sam/CETM50 - 2022_3 - Assignment Data/user_data.xml")

## get the parent tag

root = xml_file.getroot()

## print the attributes of the first tag

e = ET.tostring(xml_file.getroot(), encoding='unicode', method='xml')
print(e)

### output

<user firstName="Jayne" lastName="Wilson" age="69" sex="Female" retired="False" dependants="1" marital_status="divorced" salary="36872" pension="0" company="Wall, Reed and Whitehouse" commute_distance="10.47" address_postcode="TD95 7FL"

Comment: Please post sample of XML data as text not as image

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: xml_file = ET.parse("E:/Research work/My connect/Sam/CETM50 - 2022_3 - Assignment Data/user_data.xml")
# get the parent tag 
root = xml_file.getroot() 

# print the root (parent) tag along with its memory location 
#print(root) 

# print the attributes of the first tag
e = ET.tostring(xml_file.getroot(), encoding='unicode', method='xml')
e

Comment: Edit the question. Show the input XML and the output XML. Share the csv as well. Explain the merge logic.